Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid bug re-rendering all elements when clicking on an element
Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid Recompose Entire List on Item Click
I am working on an Android project using Jetpack Compose to create a movie list application. I want to update the posterPath of a specific item in a LazyVerticalGrid without recomposing the entire list. However, when I click on an item, the entire list gets recomposed. Below is my code:
@Composable
fun MovieItem(movie: Movie, position: Int, onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Rebugger(trackMap = mapOf("movie" to movie, "onClick" to onClick))
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(5.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black, customBorderShape)
            .background(Color.White, customShape)
            .height(200.dp)
            .clip(customShape)
            .clickable { onClick(position) }
    ) {
        GetImage(
            movie.posterPath,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .scale(1.8f)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun MovieList(movies: List<Movie>, onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(10.dp),
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            movies,
            key = { _, movie -> movie.id },
        ) { index, movie ->
            MovieItem(movie = movie, position = index, onClick = onClick)
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MovieScreen(
    viewModel: MovieViewModel = androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel(),
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.getMovies(getRequestModel())
    }
    val movieUiState by viewModel.movies.collectAsState()
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.DarkGray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        when (movieUiState) {
            is MovieUiState.Success -> {
                val movies = (movieUiState as MovieUiState.Success).movies
                MovieList(movies = movies, onClick = { index ->
                    viewModel.changeData(index)
                })
            }
            // Other states
        }
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class MovieViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val movieUseCase: MovieUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _movies = MutableStateFlow<MovieUiState>(MovieUiState.Loading)
    val movies = _movies.asStateFlow()

    fun getMovies(request: MovieRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            movieUseCase.invoke(request).collect { result ->
                result.onSuccess { response ->
                    if (response.results.isNotEmpty()) {
                        _movies.emit(MovieUiState.Success(response.results.toMutableStateList()))
                    } else {
                        _movies.emit(MovieUiState.Empty)
                    }
                }.onFailure { error ->
                    _movies.emit(MovieUiState.Error(error.localizedMessage.orEmpty()))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun changeData(movieIndex: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val currentState = _movies.value
            if (currentState is MovieUiState.Success) {
                val updatedMovies = currentState.movies.apply {
                    this[movieIndex] = this[movieIndex].copy(posterPath = this[movieIndex].backdropPath)
                }
                _movies.emit(MovieUiState.Success(updatedMovies))
            }
        }
    }
}


When I click on an item, I expect only the clicked item to recompose with its posterPath updated to its backdropPath. However, the entire list recomposes. What could be causing this issue and how can I ensure that only the relevant item is recomposed?

It's not a bug, it's normal behavior. With each item click you're changing the _movies and emitting a new value for it which in turn recomposes MovieScreen then MovieList then MovieItem which is not bad unless in your case it's not skipping items that aren't changed and that could be from various reasons, maybe your Movie class is not stable, Lists are always unstable and even your lambdas may be unstable, any of them could lead to unnecessary recomposions.

Did you try enabling strong skipping mode? It was built for specifically these kind of cases (unstable lambdas) as per the blog post.

@ianhanniballake thank you, it worked with strong skipping mode
